# Selenium - Unable to locate such element while scraping google maps reveiws

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-maps, web-scraping, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape google maps reviews but when I try to implement the scroll part, selenium throws error.

Here's my code

```
def __scroll(self):
        scrollable_div = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.section-layout.section-scrollbox.scrollable-y.scrollable-show')
        self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', scrollable_div)
```

this is just the scroll part and here selenium throws the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.section-layout.section-scrollbox.mapsConsumerUiCommonScrollable__scrollable-y.mapsConsumerUiCommonScrollable__scrollable-show"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.212)
```

I tried other suggestion on github but none worked. Any ideas How I could implement this part?

**UPD**:
This is the link to google maps used:
https://www.google.com/maps/place/El+TabanKo/@42.848117,-2.6741402,19z/data=!4m15!1m7!3m6!1s0xd4fc26be313bc85:0xb10d327c782f87fa!2sCorrer%C3%ADa+Kalea,+45,+01001+Gasteiz,+Araba!3b1!8m2!3d42.8480012!4d-2.6737255!3m6!1s0xd4fc26be26c5be1:0x5f5e0ee05fe08041!8m2!3d42.8481171!4d-2.6735931!9m1!1b1

Comment: Can you provide a link to the web page?

Comment: You are getting exception for this `selector":"div.section-layout.section-scrollbox.mapsConsumerUiCommonScrollable__scrollable-y.mapsConsumerUiCommonScrollable__scrollable-show` please share the relevant code.

Comment: Here's a sample url: https://www.google.com/maps/place/El+TabanKo/@42.848117,-2.6741402,19z/data=!4m15!1m7!3m6!1s0xd4fc26be313bc85:0xb10d327c782f87fa!2sCorrer%C3%ADa+Kalea,+45,+01001+Gasteiz,+Araba!3b1!8m2!3d42.8480012!4d-2.6737255!3m6!1s0xd4fc26be26c5be1:0x5f5e0ee05fe08041!8m2!3d42.8481171!4d-2.6735931!9m1!1b1 @Prophet

Comment: But its basically almost all Google Maps places reviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see, the correct and the unique css selector for that element is

```
div.section-layout.section-scrollbox
```

So, try this:

```
scrollable_div = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.section-layout.section-scrollbox')
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, but can you tell me how did you figure out the correct selector? I tried inspecting the page source but couldnt figure it out. but now its throwing ```Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded ```

Comment: I just opened the page and checked the elements in dev tools. The last 2 classnames you added were not actually correct. I guess they are added after scrolling the element etc.

Comment: Yea, and I think thats what's needed to extract the reviews since just adding in the name itself throws js recursion error